# Paypal payflow have two recurring subscriptions in one transaction

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

My website is in a situation where we allow the users to subscribe to multiple things at once, with multiple pay periods. I'm still new to to paypal payflow, so i'm not 100% sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is definitely possible. The way you would be able to do it is to create multiple different Recurring payment profiles.

Example:
Your customer wants to subscribe to three different magazines, all with different prices, and different billing dates. When the customer submits their form, you make 3 http requests to the payflow service, creating 3 separate profiles for one customer. You will also be able to manage these profiles separately.

You can go through the [Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/) for Recurring Billing for specifics.

Comment: Is the only possible with the payflow API?